# I can't insert data in my db cause of an empty primarykey

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm new to PHP, MySQL and working on an project for my school. I need to make a form that inserts new students into a database.

I need to have an primary key named `studentnummer` so I can use this later on, but this needs to be created in the database table not in the form. When I try to insert the data of the form in the table I'll get an error saying I need to insert data in table row 1 *(this is the primary key which is AI and an INT)*

I've got the following for PHP and MySQL:

```
require ("connection.php");

//gets the data from the form
$voornaam = $_REQUEST['voornaam'];
$tussenvoegsel = $_REQUEST['tussenvoegsel'];
$achternaam = $_REQUEST['achternaam'];
$geboortedatum = $_REQUEST['geboortedatum'];
$woonplaats = $_REQUEST['woonplaats'];
$straat = $_REQUEST['straat'];
$huisnummer = $_REQUEST['huisnummer'];
$postcode = $_REQUEST['postcode'];
$telefoonnummer = $_REQUEST['telefoonnummer'];
$mobielnummer = $_REQUEST['mobielnummer'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$voor = $_REQUEST['voor'];
$motivatie = $_REQUEST['motivatie'];
$alt = $_REQUEST['alt'];

$tbl_name ="studenten";//db table name
$sql_ins = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tbl_name values('??studentnummer??','$voornaam', '$tussenvoegsel', '$achternaam', '$geboortedatum', '$woonplaats', '$straat', '$huisnummer', ' $postcode' , '$telefoonnummer', '$mobielnummer', '$email', '$voor', '$motivatie', '$alt')");
```

This is a [printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEhny.png) from my table stucture. If anyone knows what I can do about this problem I would appreciate it very much!!!

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have your sql table set to auto increment the primary key?

Comment: Where is your column list? [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insert a `NULL` into an auto_increment primary key field, mysql will supply the value for you, so

```
INSERT INTO $tbl_name VALUES(NULL, blah blah blah)
```

and then you can retrieve the generated value with

```
$studentnummer = mysql_insert_id();
```

Note that you shouldn't be using the mysql_*() functions. They're deprecrated. Consider switching to mysqli or PDO

Comment: Thank you  very much for the quick response! I'll take a look at mysqli and PDO! But for now, if tried:

    $tbl_name ="studenten";
    $sql_ins = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tbl_name values(NULL,'$voornaam', '$tussenvoegsel', '$achternaam', '$geboortedatum', '$woonplaats', '$straat', '$huisnummer', ' $postcode' , '$telefoonnummer', '$mobielnummer', '$email', '$voor', '$motivatie', '$alt')"); 

but it doesn't work. I've also tried to change NULL to ('','bla' but  this doesn't work either

Comment: It works!!! thank you! I forgot to make an '' at the and of my query for the wachtwoord section in my db. Thank you!:D

Answer (score 0):

Please try this-

$sql_ins = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tbl_name values('','$voornaam', '$tussenvoegsel', '$achternaam', '$geboortedatum', '$woonplaats', '$straat', '$huisnummer', ' $postcode' , '$telefoonnummer', '$mobielnummer', '$email', '$voor', '$motivatie', '$alt')");